# HTML / JavaScript Selectable Timeline

Tags: javascript, html, timeline

Where can I find an off-the-shelf selectable HTML and JavaScript timeline for choosing date ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Flot: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/selection.html.